# What is the practical purpose of RAM and CPU in game development?

Tags: graphics, gpu, cpu, game-engine, ram

I was wondering, for practical purposes, what the CPU and RAM actually do in regards to game development?

My understanding is that a CPU performs all of the calculations in a game, such as collision checks, condition checks, math equations, creating objects, etc.
And the RAM stores all of the data that needs to be remembered, such as Assets, Variables, etc.

Is that correct?

And what then handles the graphics rendering, and how does a graphics card fit into all of this? I know to play high end games you need a high end graphics card, but I am not sure what it actually does, in practical terms.

Comment: This seems to be a question about "general computing hardware", and thus off-topic here.

Answer (score 1):

Games have usually these parts:

1. **UI**

   This is responsible for user/game interaction like movement, object usage, handling of Keyboard, mouse, joystick, etc. The **I/O** part is done on **CPU** side interacting with **OS**. And usually is not demanding.

   The most problematic part is object selection (for example want open door, turn switch on etc) which requires to compute the position and correspondent object in the game world. For this is used both **CPU** and **GFX**. For example **OpenGL** can return the index of rendered object on specific screen position during rendering (so usually at almost no cost). However This technique selects only visible objects and you can not select object covered by something else (like in many games you need to change view position to select properly). For more precise/comfort selection is **CPU** used but in that case all the selectable objects must be present in **CPU** side **RAM**. If the number and or complexity of selectable objects is high then this is really demanding on the **CPU**.
2. **World physics**

   This simulates all the movements, collisions, even effects etc. Nowadays is done by both **CPU** and or **GFX**. The memory and processing power requirements of this task depends on the number of simulated objects and physics effects simulated.
3. **World/Game logic**

   Here comes the situation coding like mission state, unlocking features, getting awards, experience progression, score counting and more. Usually this is not demanding at all And done solely in **CPU** side.
4. **Render**

   This stuff is done mostly on **GFX** side (if not counting simple **2D** logic games which are possible on **CPU** side easily). All the stuff is usually stored on **GFX** side **MEM** but in some cases a copy in **CPU** side **MEM** is present too. The size of **GFX** memory limits rendering screen resolution, number and quality of textures and complexity of scene stored. If any of the parameter exceeds **GFX** troughoutput then the whole rendering goes down with huge fps drops. In such case usually lovering screen resolution helps as the rendering techniques require many count of shadow buffers with the screen resolution (or its multiple).

   The computational power of **GFX** affects the max complexity of the scene and count of effects or rendering passes possible.
5. **Sound**

   This can sometimes take a lot of processing and memory too. Usually done with **CPU** and its side **MEM** and accelerated by current sound **HW**. For procedurally generated sounds and effects can this be as demanding as **GFX** layer. However games usually use static samples instead and just they amplitude and relative position is computed which is not that much demanding.
6. **AI**

   This is to drive all the bots NPCs or whatever in the game. This is done on **CPU** side and the requirements depends on their count and **AI** quality.  Usually processing power is the most important as this usually does not need to much of memory per entity.
7. **Network**

   Done on **CPU** side and usually not that demanding (except for server side which can take a lot of **MEM** too). The speed is usually determined by the network **HW** and connection and not by **CPU** processing power.